# How to flush complex query cache on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.1

I have this query:

```
    $begin = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
    $end = $endDate->format('Y-m-d');

    $model = $this->model;

    $days = \Cache::remember('query:get_sales:' . $userId . ':' . $begin . ':' . $end, 5,
        function() use($model, $begin, $end) {

        return $model->select([
            \DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as `date`'),
            \DB::raw('SUM(amount) as `total`')
        ])
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $begin)
            ->where('created_at', '<=', $end)
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
            ->lists('total', 'date');
    });
```

As you can see I cache it, but I also want to flush the index `query:get_sales:$userId:*`. The `*` means I want to flush every cache that it's key begins with this string.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you put a tag on the cache? Then you can use `Cache::tags('tag_name')->flush();` to flush. You can find the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache#cache-tags)